Exploring Lower Bound Calculations for Optimality in TSP Solutions Using k-Exchanges
I am currently exploring a mathematical approach to calculating the minimal number of comparisons required to establish the optimality of a solution in combinatorial problems, particularly in the Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP).
The goal of my work is to determine the lower bound for the number of comparisons needed to connect a given optimal solution to all other possible solutions in the solution space. The key idea is to use

k-exchanges as a local comparison mechanism to test if a solution is optimal in relation to others, thereby reducing the search space efficiently.
1. The Concept:
In the TSP, the problem can be framed as comparing a given solution to all other permutations of cities. The minimal number of comparisons necessary to prove that a solution is optimal is of particular interest.
My approach uses

k-exchanges (exchanging

k elements between two solutions) as the primary tool to perform these comparisons. This reduces the solution space by eliminating non-optimal solutions without the need to compare every possible permutation.
The minimal number of comparisons can be approximated using the following formula:
$$
C_{\text{min}} = \sum_{k=2}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k}
$$
where ( n ) is the number of cities.
This formula captures the lower bound for the minimal number of comparisons required to relate the optimal solution to all others.
2. Transitivity in Comparisons:
One aspect of this approach that I find interesting is the ability to reduce the number of comparisons through the transitivity of comparisons. Once a solution is compared to another, relationships between solutions can be inferred transitivity, which means that the number of comparisons can be reduced by not requiring direct pairwise comparisons for every solution.
3. Question for Discussion:

Does the minimal number of comparisons needed to link an optimal solution to all other possible solutions in the TSP define a valid lower bound for the problem's complexity?

I would greatly appreciate any insights, feedback, or suggestions from the community regarding the mathematical validity of this approach or any potential improvements.
Thank you!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I think these are good research questions. But the scope of the question might be too broad as of now.

@SiongThyeGoh Thank you for your feedback (it's my first post) !
I’m particularly interested in whether the minimal number of comparisons needed to connect an optimal solution to all other solutions in TSP can define a valid lower bound for the problem’s complexity.
I’d appreciate any insights on:

Similar approaches in combinatorial optimization for establishing lower bounds via comparisons.
The effectiveness of k-exchanges in reducing comparisons for TSP.


I hope you will end up with a research publication :)
